# Reading a cookie in a different application in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I have an application in Asp.Net and at a click of a button it is supposed to launch another mapping application. In that application the credentials of the user like user name and Email are required. So, I was trying to set a cookie and fix the domain of the cookie to that application but I am not able to see the cookie in that application. I am not really sure what is going wrong or if I have made some mistake in the cookie.

```
         MembershipUser usr = Membership.GetUser();
    Guid newUserId = (Guid)usr.ProviderUserKey;
    HttpCookie SampleCookie = new HttpCookie("UserInfo");
    Response.Cookies["UserInfo"]["UserName"] = usr.UserName;
    Response.Cookies["UserInfo"]["Email"] = usr.Email;
    SampleCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(SampleCookie);
    SampleCookie.Domain = "http://157.182.212.204/MAP";
```

Thank you once again for the help.

Code for MAP application:

```
          function Get_Cookie( check_name ) {
            // first we'll split this cookie up into name/value pairs
            // note: document.cookie only returns name=value, not the other components

            var a_all_cookies = document.cookie.split( ';' );
            var a_temp_cookie = '';
            var cookie_name = '';
            var cookie_value = '';
            var b_cookie_found = false; // set boolean t/f default f

            for ( i = 0; i < a_all_cookies.length; i++ )
            {
                // now we'll split apart each name=value pair
                a_temp_cookie = a_all_cookies[i].split( '=' );


                // and trim left/right whitespace while we're at it
                cookie_name = a_temp_cookie[0].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');

                // if the extracted name matches passed check_name
                if ( cookie_name == check_name )
                {
                    b_cookie_found = true;
                    // we need to handle case where cookie has no value but exists (no = sign, that is):
                    if ( a_temp_cookie.length > 1 )
                    {
                        cookie_value = unescape( a_temp_cookie[1].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '') );
                    }
                    // note that in cases where cookie is initialized but no value, null is returned
                    return cookie_value;
                    break;
                }
                a_temp_cookie = null;
                cookie_name = '';
            }
            if ( !b_cookie_found )
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        function Delete_Cookie( name, path, domain ) {
            if ( Get_Cookie( name ) ) document.cookie = name + "=" +
                    ( ( path ) ? ";path=" + path : "") +
                    ( ( domain ) ? ";domain=" + domain : "" ) +
                    ";expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT";
        }

                    alert(Get_Cookie("UserName"));
```

The code for the WVWRAPICt page RESET.aspx.cs is given below...This is where the cookie is being set

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Security;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
    using System.Xml.Linq;
  public partial class RESET_RESET : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            Menu Nav = Master.FindControl("NavigationMenu1") as Menu;
    MenuItemCollection Menu = Nav.Items;
    foreach (MenuItem item in Menu)
    {
        string name = item.Text.ToString();
        if (name == "ADMIN")
        {
            item.Enabled = User.IsInRole("Administrator");
        }
        if (name == "ICT")
        {
            item.Selected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            item.Selected = false;
        }
    }
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MembershipUser usr = Membership.GetUser();
    Guid newUserId = (Guid)usr.ProviderUserKey;
    HttpCookie SampleCookie = new HttpCookie("UserInfo");
    SampleCookie["UserName"] = usr.UserName;
    SampleCookie["Email"] = usr.Email;
    string connectionString =
  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    string checkSiteEventIDSQL = "Select * from UserProfiles WHERE UserId='" + newUserId + "'";

    using (SqlConnection myConnection1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            myConnection1.Open();
            SqlCommand myCommand1 = new SqlCommand(checkSiteEventIDSQL, myConnection1);
            SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand1.ExecuteReader();
            if (myReader.HasRows)
            {
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    string Agency = (myReader.GetValue(2)).ToString();
                    SampleCookie["Agency"] = Agency;

                }


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection1.Close();
        }
    }
    SampleCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
     SampleCookie.Domain = "157.182.212.204/MAP";
    // SampleCookie.Path = "/MAP";
    Response.Cookies.Add(SampleCookie);

   Response.Redirect("http://157.182.212.204/MAP/index.html");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding trouble with the way you are setting your cookie... you're not going to find the cookie in the response unless you've added it to the response.  (And if you ARE finding it, you're just over-writing that cookie a couple lines later). Just edit the cookie directly then add to the cookie jar.  Also I believe the MAP should be in the path property of the cookie (not sure how big of a difference it makes).  As far as I know you don't want the http in the domain (again, not sure if the browser is smart enough to handle).

```
MembershipUser usr = Membership.GetUser();
    Guid newUserId = (Guid)usr.ProviderUserKey;
    HttpCookie sampleCookie = new HttpCookie("UserInfo");
    sampleCookie["UserName"] = usr.UserName;
    sampleCookie["Email"] = usr.Email;
    sampleCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
    sampleCookie.Domain = "157.182.212.204";
    sampleCookie.Path = "/MAP";
    Response.Cookies.Add(sampleCookie);
```

Cookies can only be set to a domain which is a 'tail' of the current FQDN.  So if your current FQDN is not 157.182.212.204, the cookie will not set in the browser.  By tail, for example, I mean http://overflow.acme.com could set a cookie for overflow.acme.com or acme.com, but not for fubar.acme.com or fubar.com.

My guess is if your application is on a different FQDN than the MAP application, you're going to need to figure a different way to pass the user name and e-mail to the map application (maybe post to a page on the map application which can set the cookie and then redirect to the appropriate page?

---

Update after you've posted some more code:

Try this:

```
   SampleCookie.Domain = "157.182.212.204";
   SampleCookie.Path = "/MAP";
   Response.Cookies.Add(SampleCookie);

   Response.Redirect("http://157.182.212.204/MAP/index.html", false);
```

Setting false on the response.redirect should cause the set cookie headers to come through.  You might need to short circuit other logic in your page if you have anything in the render events

Or just pass the stuff in a query string.  You're not using HttpOnly cookies (so a user could inject the cookies).

Comment: I tried that but it does not seem to work...any other idea plzzzzz

Comment: That did not help either.Actually my application is at 157.182.212.204/WVWRAPICT and on a click of a button it calls 157.182.212.204/MAP so I guess it is the same FQDN. I am not sure what else could be the problem...Please help and this is the fist time I am doing something of this kind. I really appreciate your help....

Comment: @user613037, don't set the path of the cookie.  That should work.

Comment: Actually install Fiddler web debugger.  In the response (to the /WVWRAPICT  application) that sets the cookie make sure you are setting a set-cookie response (under headers tab).  Then see if the cookie is being sent on the request to the /MAPS application (in the request headers tab).

Comment: I tried by not setting the path ...but no help and I even tried installing fiddler but I dont see my application in the kist od the applications on the left. Not sure how to use it...but its really frustrating that even after doing everything it does not seem to work....Please help...

Comment: Are you doing a response.redirect after setting the cookie?  How do you move from this server code which sets the cookie in WVWRAPICT to the server code which reads the cookie in MAP?

Comment: I am actually doing a response.redirect after setting the cookie...and it gets redirected to a page RESET.aspx that is a part of the WVWRAPICT and not MAP..On Reset.apx we have a launch button that launches the mapping application and the page gets redirected to 157.182.212.204/MAP/index.html...which is the mapping application...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is why you're not getting your cookies then.  My recommendation would be to instead set the cookie in RESET.aspx or use Response.Redirect("RESET.aspx", false); which will not abort the thread (and thus cookies should be set).

Comment: So, now it is working and I can see the cookies on the RESET.aspx page(I could not see the cookies before). Here i am still setting the cookies on the old page but not on Reset.aspx.I am trying to fix the domain to the MAP application in the Reset.Aspx but that does not help as well...I m not sure but theblem lies in sending the cookie to the MAP application..Any better way I can do that....

Comment: I tried setting the cookie in the Reset.aspx page but that did not help either...I still cannot see the cookie in the mapping application...I tried setting the domain and path and I tried even without setting the domain and path but nothing helps me in seeing the cookie in the mapping application...

Comment: I'm glad we made it further!  I would try setting the domain but not the path.  That way your cookie will show up for applications on 157.182.212.204.

Comment: No, That does not help either....what else can be done...Sorry for so much trouble...

Comment: If you would like to post more code (excerpt from the cookie setting page and the cookie reading page) I might be able to help more.  Right now I'm pretty stuck on the information available.

Comment: I am sory for the delay but here is the code for the cookie setting and cookie reading. By the way I forgot to mention that the other application MAP is basically written in flex...It is a flex application. The codes are given below

Comment: The codes are given below in the answer...It does not allow me to put the code here in the comment